# ~4K rows insertion to DB per user - design & performance

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, hibernate

I'm writing an application that allows each user to label English words in three categories (some lexical exercise).

The main DB table, **Word**, contains ~4K different rows of words.
The **Label** table contains 3 labels.
--> The **Word-Label** table (that contains 3 columns: word_id, label_id, user_id) will add 4K rows per user (let's assume all the words starts with some pre-defined label when user register to the system).

The problem is that the table will grow very fast. 1:4000 (user/row) is bad in my opinion.

What can you suggest here to eliminate such a huge table? I've read that table-per-user is also considered bad practice.

In addition, I'm using Spring & Hibernate and the 4K insertions after the user get registered for the first time is pretty tough and takes time.

I can consider some NoSQL solution or another tool than Hibernate, but I'm consisting to use **Spring & Java** - so suggest something properly.

Will be glad for your help here!

Comment: How many users do you expect to have?  Are the words or the labels dynamic (will new ones be added over time)?  I'm guessing that this is not really a problem.  4k rows per user is not a big deal.

Comment: There is no limit to the number of users. Right now 1K-5K. The labels are static (three, each with a unique id). The words are also static (I can add more than 4K). If 4K rows per user is not a big deal, why it takes 1-2 minutes to insert them to a table using hibernate?

Comment: . . Take that up with Hibernate.  Here is a SQL Fiddle that inserts 4,000 rows in no more than a second or so:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/12849/1.  Your size constraints are not big for a reasonably powerful database running on reasonable hardware.

Comment: [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7b6c99f2d4c3240089245ceb7c2a46c9)'s a db<>fiddle how the creation of you're DB could look like. At the end a user is created including the insertion of initial records in the mapping table with a default label for each word. Takes around 2 secs for me to load including the HTTPS overhead! That's not an unacceptable time I'd say.

Answer (score 3):

There is no issue with data size.  You may have an issue with Hibernate, but that is another issue.

If you end up with thousands of users, you'll have a few tens of millions of rows.  That is not a large number of rows.  If you want to insert default labels for a new user, then the code would look something like this:

```
insert into userLabels (userId, wordId, label)
    select :userId, w.wordId, <default label>
    from words w;
```

I would be surprised if this took more than a second or two.

If you knew that you would be having millions of users, then size might be more of an issue.  The best solution would require better understanding of the application.  The solution might vary from partitioning the tables, using arrays, or coming up with a different structure for representing your data.

You probably want various indexes on your tables to speed performance, but that depends on the queries you want to run.  You might consider using a native interface to the database.  Your use-case doesn't seem particularly complicated, so I don't know what advantage Hibernate or similar layers gets you.

Answer (score 1):

First approach, you will just add new row to word-label for user after action. So, not every user will probably have 4k rows in that table. Now, when your database - query and stuff around that functionality will be a problem (bottleneck) then try to fix the issue and improve performance.

There are many performance tricks in sql databases you can use. For example, you wrote about table per user. That's not quite the best solution, next example, in mysql, u can create table patitions and it will be handled as one table but with performance improvement.

Second approach, for this type of data, of cource some NoSQL like MongoDB would perform great.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas! The problem is even if I will add after a user action, each user can reach 4K rows...

Answer (score 0):

you could encode the user responsse-map into a 4000 entry bit-array, or string if you don't need the relational capabilities of the database

then it would be one record per user.

```
create table user_words (userid int, wiorddata text);
insert into user_words values (1,'YNYYNmmmYY'/* ... */ );
```

you application would need to have the list of words and kniow which wird each character refers to.

Comment: Can you give me an example?